# May i list down iPhone apps in my app?

Tags: iphone, ios, web-services, app-store

I want to know that may i list down and show iphone apps from app store? is there any web service or some other way to get the app links of app store?

Comment: You might find some links listed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689711/itunes-app-store-api) useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do is by using [iTunes Link Maker](http://itunes.apple.com/linkmaker/) and have a button action on its click event you can open the URL you get from the link maker.

For example i've got the URL for Rovio mobile apps using `iTunes Link Maker`, on click of it you'll get list of all apps provided by rovio. Here is the link http://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/rovio-mobile-ltd./id298910979?ign-mpt=uo%3D4

```
-(void)yourButtonAction
{

 NSString*thePath=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/rovio-mobile-ltd./id298910979?ign-mpt=uo%3D4"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:thePath]];

}
```

**Note**: This works only on device, simulator doesn't have app store app installed. You'll get "Safari cannot open this website" error in the simulator.

Comment: hmmm thanx but if i want to list down all the apps or by price then?
i.e. i want to see all the apps of price 1.99$. then how can i get it?

Comment: @Mashhadi i just did a search to sort itunes result by price, there seem to be no options for that, so i'm guessing your chances of getting a similar API is pretty thin.

Comment: @Mashhadi you can look up at http://ax.itunes.apple.com/rss, this gives list of all RSS feed that's available for itunes store search criteria.

Comment: @iNoobi thanx i have already checked it and i think this is the only way. i'll have to sort them by my self :)